Isolate (switch off) 2 units from circuit of several recessed LED lights
I have a lighting circuit with several slim LED pot-lights that are controlled with a dimmer switch. I added a second switch (see diagram below) so that I can independently turn one of the lights off while the others in the room remain on.

Hopefully my diagram makes sense, I'd like to change things so that two lights are now turned off by that same switch.

EDIT:
Thanks for you answers! How does the following updated diagram look?
I'm trying to retain the existing wiring as much as possible in case I ever need to remove the second switch and revert my changes, hence the seemingly unnecessary junction boxes :)


Using your own picture seems that you can connect up Light B the same way that Light A is connected.


This works but depending on the physical layout it might be easier to daisy-chain the double-switched lights instead of running them both back to the junction box.  Also, OP's picture is a little vague about routing of the neutral, and yours is a little worse than vague, though I'm sure not on purpose.  I could give the earlier picture some benefit of the doubt but here, the neutral can't do that.

Thanks for your input on my diagram Michael, I'm going to see how this would translate into my real world wiring setup

More like this.  Forgive the crude drawing.  Two chains of lights, one switched, the other double-switched. You don't need an extra junction box.  Take a feed off any of the lights, the one closest to the second switch position.  Run live and neutral to the switch.   From there go to any of the double-switched lights, and from there chain them just like the first chain.
It's important that all the double-switched lights' neutral wires return via the same path as their live wires.  You cannot leave the neutrals connected to the old chain and only modify the lives.


Thanks Jay, I have edited my question with an updated diagram. Due to previously unmentioned constraints I'm not sure that I'll be able to change the wiring to this nice streamlined layout.

"Streamlined" is whatever you want it to be.  :)   Just don't do the red X's ... with two new junction boxes be a little careful to keep lives and neutrals together on every part of every circuit.

Thanks for the advice, I think I now have a better idea on how to proceed. I'll be VERY careful while connecting all those wires through the junction boxes and hopefully my updated diagram doesn't have any red X type neutral connections!
